# Detect Saturday and Sunday and add x amount of days to Monday

Tags: php, date, date-math

I want it to automatically add days until Monday if someone choose Friday.
Imagine `$leavefrom` is 3-1-2014 which is Thursday, and `$leaveto` is 3-2-2014 is Friday. `$totaldays` are calculated based on the date. Therefore it is 2 days.

```
<?php
$x = 0;

$date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $leavefrom);
$date2 = str_replace('-', '/', $leaveto);

while ($x < $totaldays) {

    $tomorrow = date('l', strtotime($date1 ."+1 days"));

    //$tomorrow = date("m-d-Y", strtotime( $date1 ."+1 days" ));
    $getday = date('D', strtotime($tomorrow));
    $x++;
    if ($getday == "Sunday" || $getday = "Saturday") {
        $tomorrow = date("m/d/Y", strtotime( $tomorrow ."+1 days" ));
    }
    $tomorrow = date("m/d/Y", strtotime( $tomorrow ."+1 days" ));
}

echo $tomorrow;
?>
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? and could you try to be a bit more clear with what you want? (I see saturday, monday, add up till friday... I'm a bit confused ;))

Comment: Ok, you see, I want to create a simple leave system, so if someone apply the leave on those 2 dates mentioned above, both date are Thursday and Friday, so the user who apply this leave will start work on Monday. I need it's date for Monday skipping Saturday and Sunday. So they will start working on 5-3-2013. Get what I mean? Hehe sorry, poor english.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to skip weekends just check to see if `$date2` is on a weekend, if so, skip ahead to the next Monday.

```
$date2 = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('n-j-Y', $leaveto);
if (in_array($date2->format('l'), array('Sunday', 'Saturday'))) {
    $date2->modify('next Monday');
}
echo $date2->format("m/d/Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `if ($getday == "Sunday" || $getday = "Saturday")` into a `while`, instead, and get rid of the last `$tomorrow = ...`. Something like this:

```
<?php
$x = 0;

$date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $leavefrom);
$date2 = str_replace('-', '/', $leaveto);

while ($x < $totaldays) {

    $tomorrow = date('l', strtotime($date1 ."+1 days"));
    $x++;

    $getday = date('D', strtotime($tomorrow));
    while ($getday == "Sunday" || $getday = "Saturday") {
        $tomorrow = date("m/d/Y", strtotime( $tomorrow ."+1 days" ));
        $getday = date('D', strtotime($tomorrow));
    }

}

echo $tomorrow;
?>
```

Comment: You sure this code is correct? I get infinite loop.

Comment: Nope, not at all. You didn't give us enough to really test with so I don't know if it works or not. Why don't you drop an `echo` inside the loop to print out the value of `$tomorrow` and `$getday`, see why it's not exiting.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution after 3 hours of head bang on the wall for being stupid, below is my code:

```
while ($daysloop <= $totaldays) {
$tomorrow1 = date("m/d/Y", strtotime( $tomorrow1 ."+1 days" ));
$dayofweek = date('w', strtotime($tomorrow1));

if ($dayofweek == 0 || $dayofweek == 6) {
$weekends = $weekends + 1;
}
$daysloop++;
}

if ($totaldays == 0) {
$totaldays = $totaldays - $weekends + 1;
}
else {
$totaldays = $totaldays - $weekends;
}
```